# useEffect doesn't re-render main parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

useEffect doesn't re-render the main parent component when I change state 'click button' in other component. When I reload page magic heapens. How should I re-render main `<App />` component on this event without reloading page?

```
const ResponsiveAppBar = () => {
const defaultDark = window.matchMedia(
    '(prefers-color-scheme: dark)'
).matches;

let [theme, setTheme] = useLocalStorage(
    'theme',
    defaultDark ? 'dark' : 'light'
);

React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('theme changed into: ', theme);
    <App />;
}, [theme]);

const switchTheme = () => {
    const newTheme = theme === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light';
    console.log(newTheme);
    setTheme(newTheme);
};
```

Comment: I'm afraid putting `<App />` inside useEffect is completely wrong, @Edgaraxx. You seem to be very new to React. I strongly suggest working through the React tutorial. There is a lot of basic knowledge you are missing ...

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is explained [here (Context - React)](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Basically, you should use React Context to share the state between parent and child components. If a child component wants to change the Theme, you can grab the `setTheme` hook from the Context and call it as needed.

Comment: thanks for advice I will try to learn Context way

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna have light and dark mode you have to be able to access the state every where to do that you should learn about [react context api](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or try to learn [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) if you to make a large scale app

Comment: thanks for advice I will try to learn Context way